# Keep application on top (even when Show Desktop button is pressed)

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there any way to keep a specific window always visible even when the Show Desktop button is pressed?

I'm working with multiple monitors, on my 2nd monitor I have several apps that I want to always keep open to Monitor things, but on pressing Show desktop they do also minimize which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no one I know was able to produce sensible solution to your problem. Assuming you do not want to simply minimize apps just to view your desktop wallpaper, you can use this workaround:

- right-click an empty area near the clock
- left click Toolbars
- left click Desktop

This will make custom toolbar / menu near the clock, so you won't be needing ShowDesktop just to launch some file that is there.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature like that in Rainlendar. It doesn't work flawlessly on Windows 7, but works. The windows flicker so I assume they actually get minimized, but they stick to the desktop. I assume this can be done by simply restoring a window after it gets minimized.